# Is there consensus on why inflation is not rising?

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation

I find it kind of odd that we are not experiencing any significant inflation recent years despit the low rates and quantitative easings.

Is there a consensus why this is the case among economists? If not, what are the mos popular explanations?

I am refering to countries in weastern EU and USA.

Comment: If you are asking about a particular country or group of countries, could you please edit your question to clarify this.

Comment: @Adam Bailey fixed

Comment: For the US ... No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about Europe, yes there is. Inflation took time to rise because commercial banks have used injected liquidities to consolidate their balance sheet instead of stimulating demands by creating credits (that did not previously exist when they make loans). This is called the [money multiplier](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_multiplier). The multiplier was *somehow* blocked (to ~$1$) because of their precaution behavior.

On [March 10, 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicopter_money#In_the_Eurozone), the [ECB](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/home/html/index.en.html) has even considered the possibility of giving 200€ per month and per person to stimulate inflation. And this with the main idea of circumventing the commercial-bank system. This unconventional monetary policy is called [monetary helicopter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicopter_money).

Comment: what does "consolidate their balance sheet " consits of?

Comment: My suspision as a layman is that all the money and low rates went into stocks and real estate thus not getting into "real" inflation driving sectors such as healthcare, food, school and infrastructure. Is that a total missconception?

Comment: @Maxed I have made a quasi-abusive use of the word "consolidate". What I meant is that the subprime crisis and its consequences have contaminated the Euro-zone's commercial banks through [securitization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Securitization), interrogating the default risk associated to their assets and liabilities. Injected liquidities have thus often been used to anticipate these potential defaults on the one hand, and also to elevate their fractional-reserve ratios on the other hand.

Comment: hmm just read something about what happend after the 08-crisis. Ít seams like alot of regluation where imposed on the banks after the crisis. Are you saying that the QE was nessesary or/and used to fullfill these demands imposed by authorities?

Comment: for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_III

Comment: @Maxed. Yes exactly, even if there were other (more delicate) possibilities than benefiting from QE to comply with Basel3: the point is that com.banks could not disentengle the uncertainty associated to the components of their balance sheets from their exposures to liquidity risks, i.e. to the fact that depositors may all want to withdraw their money at the same time... which event characterizes all what liquidity risk is about: fractional-reserve ratios pushed to their max. = [full-reserve banking](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-reserve_banking) = no liqu.risk. B3 is not as extreme.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not a professional economist so take what I say with a pinch of salt; but my understanding is that the central bank in Germany, one of the strongest central banks in Europe, has very strong regulations and policies against re-igniting inflation because of the effects of hyper-inflation during the inter-war period.

Comment: and this forces banks and inverstors to put all the money in certain corners of the economy where they can make some money? But these corners are also not contributing to inflation?

Comment: @Maxed: Germany is already a strong economy last time I looked so people are making plenty of money whilst adhering to the Banks anti-inflation strategy.

Comment: @Maxed: Isn’t that an argument for extending regulation to tax havens and the like so such reckless policies can’t be pursued?

Comment: Thats a complicated question. To many variables,I am just trying to understand the inflation atm. What justice means or is I leave alone for now.

Comment: @Mozi the argument that consists in saying that Germany is "afraid" of inflation is, admittedly, widespread. But this argument is only political, not technical... not to say instrumentalized.

Comment: @maxed: Economics without justice is not economics ...

Comment: @kanak: It’s a false simplification that politics is not a part of economics; one of the oroginary names for this discipline was political economy. As for technicalities, techniques and instruments, well we could go into how the Bundesbank sets, monitors and achieves these aims.